# PHPUnit 10 - Coverage with Attributes

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

Is it me or is it impossible to recreate the docblock metadata "@covers" with the "new" (they've been around for a while now) Attribute approach?

We used to write our tests like so:

```php
/**
 * @coversDefaultClass \App\Foo
 */
final class FooTest
{
    /**
     * @test
     * @covers ::bar
     */
    public function can_it_bar(): void
    {
    }
}
```

But for the life of me I can't seem to reproduce the same results with `#[CoversClass]` and/or `#[CoversFunction]`.

Anyone already figured this out?

We want to start migrating to Attributes because of the announcement made here that in PHPUnit 12 support for metadata in docblocks will be removed:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4502

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it's impossible to reproduce the same behavior, but as far as I can understand you have to re-write you code like this:

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\Attributes\CoversClass;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Attributes\CoversFunction;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Attributes\Test;

#[CoversClass(\App\Foo::class)]
#[CoversFunction('bar')]
final class FooTest
{
  #[Test]
  public function can_it_bar(): void
  {
  }
}
```

You can even automate this using [Rector and custom PhpUnit rules](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-phpunit/blob/main/docs/rector_rules_overview.md#coversannotationwithvaluetoattributerector).

In my opinion the easiest thing to do is not use `CoversFunction` anymore and only use `CoversClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find informations [here](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.0/attributes.html#)

You have attributes in class level and/or method level and if they exists, annotations are ignored.

I hope that helps you